# Problem saving greek letters in normal style while exporting as .pdf [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am having trouble generating greek letters as normal style while exporting in **.pdf** format while **.fig** and **.png** formats have no issues doing so.

Once the figure is generated, this is how

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);

figure('name','test');
plot(x,y);
xlabel('d [\rm{µ}m]'); 
ylabel('\eta');
legend('d = \rm{µ}m');

print( '-dpdf', '-painters', 'test')
```

[image]

Could someone explain why am I having these issues only with the **.pdf** format?

And how to fix the problem?

Comment: Not reproducible for me on R2018a (OS: Win10)

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks for trying.

Comment: not reproducible in R2020a (online) either